# udevadm to retrieve device attribute

Tags: linux-kernel, driver, udev

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Ethernet chip: Intel I210

Ethernet driver: igb

I've looked into my etherent device attribute.
By typing the command

```
udevadm info -p -a /sys/class/net/eth0
```

I got the following information:

```
looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:02:00.0/net/eth0':
    KERNEL=="eth0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="net"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{mtu}=="1500"
    ATTR{type}=="1"
    ATTR{netdev_group}=="0"
    ATTR{flags}=="0x1003"
    ATTR{speed}=="1000"
    ATTR{dormant}=="0"
    ATTR{addr_assign_type}=="0"
    ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0"
    ATTR{duplex}=="full"
    ATTR{gro_flush_timeout}=="0"
    ATTR{iflink}=="2"
    ATTR{addr_len}=="6"
    ATTR{address}=="0c:c4:7a:12:b4:e4"
    ATTR{operstate}=="up"
    ATTR{carrier_changes}=="2"
    ATTR{broadcast}=="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff"
    ATTR{tx_queue_len}=="1000"
    ATTR{dev_port}=="0"
    ATTR{ifalias}==""
    ATTR{ifindex}=="2"
    ATTR{link_mode}=="0"
    ATTR{carrier}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:02:00.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:02:00.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="igb"
    ATTRS{irq}=="18"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x15d9"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x020000"
    ATTRS{index}=="1"
    ATTRS{label}==" Intel Ethernet controller#1 i210"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,0000000f"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x1533"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-3"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x1533"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"
```

Some questions below:

1. what is the relationship between "device" and "parent device"
2. Are these attributes retrieved from firmware ( on device ) or BIOS or driver ?
3. Is it possible to modify the attribute value ?

I ask this is because as you may know, Ubuntu 15.10 and newer version has taken the rule of predictable network interface names. For the onboard device, it will be recognized as "`enox`" and `x` means its index.

Unfortunately, on my host, my two ethernets have the same index and this causes the race condition. If I did not revert back to the original network interface naming rule, the boot is gonna take about 4 mins.

I suspect it's the firmware issue.

Comment: 1. In this case eth0 is just a child of the actual PCI device. 2. The attributes in most cases are neither from BIOS, nor from card firmware, though it might be some of them. 3. Depending to the driver and net framework. 4. Your problem is udev specific, driver naming is done in udev, it is almost distribution agnostic behavior. You are looking to the wrong place.

Comment: @0andriy for the second point, so where do these attributes come from ? For the fourth point, i agree with you. however, for the case of udev to handle interface name, i found the following information:

/*
 * Predictable network interface device names based on:
 *  - firmware/bios-provided index numbers for on-board devices

Comment: and that's why I suspect the index makes the system boot slow.

Comment: @0andriy any further discussion to this ?

Comment: Nope, I guess you might google for some answers. I'm just not seeing any real question here.

Comment: @0andriy I traced down the udev code and found out there info are reported from /sys/class/net/... I think these info might be reported from driver. The driver may get these info from Lan chip firmware. I am not so sure about it and this is my question posted here.

Comment: Yes, part of them would be from firmware. In any case in OS you have a driver which allows you to alter some settings.

Comment: @0andriy is my assumption correct ? These info is reported from igb driver and the driver got this info from Lan chip firmware. If this is correct, is there anyway I could trace down the path before the firmware ?

Comment: @0andriy Would you agree with me to close this question ? Since it's only you and me in the discussion thread and we did not come out with the real answer. I would like to close this one and start a new question focusing on /sys/class/net/... information.

Comment: Up to you. I would suggest to look into driver sources (If I would be you I would go that way).

Comment: @0andriy yea,that's wat i am looking into. thanks for the discussion.